# Google for Jobs Location of job showing up is incorrect (Google is using our Company HQ)

Tags: google-search

I am having an issue with multiple Job Postings on our website.

We offer jobs in multiple location across Canada.  All job pages contain an "`LD+JSON`" structured data for a jobPosting, based on Google's documentation for JobPostings:
    https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting

Each job postings include a jobLocation section, containing a city, province and country.  We do not have access to street-level address information.

While our jobPostings show up on Google for Jobs, their location show up with our CompanyHQ's address, "Ottawa, ON (+1 other)".

This page is a good example:
https://altisprofessional.com/Opportunity?IsASearch=true&OpportunityNumber=2060658
While the metadata on this page clearly indicates the jobLocation to be "Toronto, Ontario, Canada", the location shows up as "Ottawa, ON", which is our company`s HQ.

[image: Google for Jobs showing wrong location]

If I change the hiringOrganization name to something bogus, then the location specified in the "`LD+JSON`" data is used and shows up correctly.

Anyone know how to get Google to display the provided jobLocation in the results?

FYI:  some people are having the same issue on Google forums...  Thought I would try the expert community here for an answer as Google seems to be silent on the issue.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/12154954?hl=en

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/9229298?hl=en

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/11342217?hl=en

Comment: The example posting has been filled.

Comment: Thanks.  I have provided a new job posting with the same issue.

Comment: That posting is gone again. I think we'd need an example JSON payload to help out, it's likely some of the fields are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help:

Perform a Google map search on the `streetAddress` you have provided as part of the `Structured Data`. If it doesn't exactly map to a business(in this case yours), Google picks the default display name as in your case.

Comment: Interesting.  I will give that a try!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  If you read my question carefully, I specify that "We do not have access to street-level address information."  We only provide "city, province and country".  Also, even if we did, being a staffing agency, we offer staffing services in WAY more cities and location then we have offices (like most staffing agencies).